# Change and refresh at runtime Generic.kl file

Tags: android, key, keycode, keymapping, scancodes

I'm doing a code that can remap keys on android. To do this i get the input from the user and with a standard map of scancodes and keycodes i rewrite at runtime the Generic.kl file changing the choosen element. After this i save and reboot. The problem is that there isn't any change. I can also delete the Generic.kl file but any change. Is there somewhere a special refresh option? Any solution?

Comment: File permissions set on root rw -r -r

Comment: Update now changes work but some input like headset button gives right scancode but wrong keycode (115 COMMAND_UNKNOWN). I'm confused.